# Laravel url previous return same page after page reload

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I tried to access the previous URL on Laravel 5.3 Homestead by several methods but all times i got the right previous page at first request then i got the same page after i refresh the page.

I am using Middleware to check the language before accessing the page

```
URL::previous();
// or
back()->getTargetUrl();
```

Language middleware

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
    $locale = $request->locale;
    $segments = $request->segments();
    $lang_sess = $request->session()->get('language');

    if (!array_key_exists($locale, Config::get('app.locales'))) :
        if (count($segments) > 1):
            $segments[0] = ($lang_sess == "") ? Config::get('app.fallback_locale') : $lang_sess;
            $re_to = implode('/', $segments);
        else:
            $locale = $request->session()->get('language', 'en');
            $re_to = "/$locale/" . implode('/', $segments);
        endif;
        return Redirect::to($re_to);
    endif;
    $request->session()->put('language', $locale);
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return $next($request);
}
```

**[SOLVED]**

as i still developing my web app, i didn't go the page through a 'href' link, i was entering it through copy and paste the URL into browser, and this causes the URL::previous to be changed after reload the page..

Case closed, thanks for all who replied and gave attention.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the middleware you mentioned?

Comment: Question edited by the language middleware, Thanks @Ross Wilson

Answer (score 2):

the 'previous URL' is stored in a session.Every time your URL changes, the `session()->get('_previous')['url']` will change to previous url.

Doing the logic this way:

```
if (url()->current() == url()->previous()) {
    url()->setPreviousUrl('xxx') // or other logic here
}
```

Comment: But what if i open the same page from another tab that already has no previous page, now the current == previous, then i get to the session to call the latest saved URL which is not exists in the tab but in the session

Comment: And also after reload the page, the current would be the same as the previous, so i also edit the session with the current value not the previous.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to page `A` from `B` . Your previous page will be `B` . But if you refresh page then you are going from `A` to page `A`.

I suggest to use cookie in this case by checking previous page , if different change cookie otherwise keep it as it is.

```
  $last_page = URL::previous();
  if(Cookie::get("previous_page") == $last_page){
       Cookie::make('previous_page',$last_page, 60);
  }
```

Now you can use this cookie value `Cookie::get ("previous_page")` in your middleware

Not tested but this would guide you.

Comment: Great, assume i opened the page into 2 tabs in browser, first tab has previous page which we already came from it, and the second tab has no actual previous page but the one in the cooki, then when redirect, i redirect to non-actual page but the one in the cookie, got it?

Comment: same agent say browser will work same for any site defined. Example : you open login page in 2 tab and logged in by submit in one tab. And then just refresh other opened tab will redirect you to home page. Because both using same session. Right ?